# Check whether a URL variable is set using JQuery

Tags: jquery, url, query-string

I would like to know whether there is a jQuery function which can check whether a variable in the URL is set.

Something similar to the isset() function in PHP

Thanks

Comment: There is not built in jQuery function for that. However you can extract the parameters and test for yourself. Search here on SO for how to extract them: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+get+URL+parameters

Answer (score 27, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have native functions to get URL parameters.

But you can write your own plugin to it:

```
$.extend({
  getUrlVars: function(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
  },
  getUrlVar: function(name){
    return $.getUrlVars()[name];
  }
});
```

Then you can do anything like it:

```
if ($.getUrlVar("MyParam") != null) {
    // Do anything...
}
```

Comment: How could you take this a step further and get the value of the parameter? I am trying to set the value of a jQuery UI datepicker if the date is set, so I need that value.

Comment: @MattAltepeter, this is exactly what happens already. It'll only return `null` if no such parameter or if the parameter doesn't have a value in the URL. If it has a value, the value will be the return.

Comment: this would be a nice addition to the actual library. I'm sure it would get good use

Answer (score 2):

jQuery does not provide such methods. But you don’t even need jQuery to do so:

```
(function() {
    var params = null;
    this.l = typeof Location !== "undefined" ? Location.prototype : window.location;
    this.l.getParameter = function(name) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.apply(this.getParameterValues(name))[0];
    };
    this.l.getParameterMap = function() {
        if (params === null) {
            params = {};
            this.search.substr(1).split("&").map(function(param) {
                if (param.length === 0) return;
                var parts = param.split("=", 2).map(decodeURIComponent);
                if (!params.hasOwnProperty(parts[0])) params[parts[0]] = [];
                params[parts[0]].push(parts.length == 2 ? parts[1] : null);
            });
        }
        return params;
    };
    this.l.getParameterNames = function() {
        var map = this.getParameterMap(), names = [];
        for (var name in map) {
            if (map.hasOwnProperty(name)) names.push(name);
        }
        return names;
    };
    this.l.getParameterValues = function(name) {
        return this.getParameterMap()[name];
    };
})();
```

This extends the `location` object with the methods `getParameter`, `getParameterMap`, `getParameterNames`, and `getParameterValues` (similar to [Java’s *ServeletRequest*](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html)) that can be used as follows:

```
if (typeof location.getParameter("foo") !== "undefined") {
    // foo parameter exists
}
```

The return values of `getParameter` have the following meaning:

- `undefined`: given parameter not present
- `null`: given parameter has no assigned value (e.g. `foo` in `a=b&foo&c=d`)
- any string value otherwise.