# Set jQuery UI datepicker date if request variable is set

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery UI datepicker widget and I would like to see if a request variable is set. When someone selects a date, a request variable `date` is set using `window.location.replace()`. After the `replace()`, I would like to use the `setDate` method to set the date, if the `date` variable is set, otherwise just use today's date.

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net example? I'm not quite sure what you need.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p7Wjc/

When the date is clicked, a URL parameter gets added and the page is reloaded using `replace()`. I need to know if the parameter is set and get the value of the parameter

Comment: @SalmanA I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001839/check-whether-a-url-variable-is-set-using-jquery

But when I tried to implement it it broke my jQuery UI datepicker. Could you give me a hint on how to implement it? Should it be in the `$(document).ready()` or?

Comment: `var qs_date = location.href.match(/[?&]date=([^&#]+)/); if(qs_date) qs_date = qs_date[1];`